# jQuery Lazy not working – with Airtable and Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, lazy-loading, airtable

**Can anyone help me out how to pass Airtable data into the 'data-src' variable for my image?**
*Details below.*

I created a simple html site, where I use Vue/Airtable to pass some images from my Airtable base to an  html object:

```
<img class="lazy" id="img1" :src="item['fields']['Photo'][0]['thumbnails']['large']['url']" alt="" v-if="item['fields']['Photo']">
```

I have included jQuery Lazy, but can't seem to get it to work – everything loads as soon as the page loads. I think I need to pass the Airtable data to a 'data-src' variable rather than ':src' – but when I try the code below, nothing appears at all:

```
<img class="lazy" id="img1" :data-src="item['fields']['Photo'][0]['thumbnails']['large']['url']" alt="" v-if="item['fields']['Photo']">
```

I just started out using Vue and Airtable, and have very little coding experience overall. Any help appreciated!

Comment: `:src-data` is not `:data-src`

Comment: @JaromandaX ah sorry that was a typo in here! I corrected it now. Do you have any idea how to fix it? :)

Comment: Please avoid posting duplicates. You've already asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64631485/how-can-i-make-my-image-and-video-content-lazy-load-airtable-vue)

Comment: @Viney Wasn't sure I framed it in the right way – but maybe I should've just edited the post instead. Will keep in mind! 